# Upgrading EE1 to EE2 database name problem in update script

Tags: ee2, ee1, config, upgrade

I'm trying to get an EE1 site up to EE2.5.5

To do this I created a clone of the live site's files. Exported the SQL from the live database and populated a "dev" database with the data then updated paths and config settings accordingly. This created a working clone (I've done this many times with no problems).

So, to clarify;
I have a live site running from a database named "clientname_live"
I have a dev site running from a database named "clientname_dev"

I have managed to get from 1.6.8 to 1.7.3 with no issues but trying to go from there up to 2.0.0 is throwing up problems.

The site uses ngen file field, structure and gypsy. I have removed gypsy completely, converted any file fields to text inputs and run the Structure update script (which appeared to run fine and do its stuff).

After uploading the necessary EE2 files and starting the update process I almost immediately hit the following error:

```
Error Number: 1146

Table 'clientname_live.exp_weblog_fields' doesn't exist

SELECT field_id FROM exp_weblog_fields WHERE field_type = 'date'

Filename: updates/ud_200.php

Line Number: 1583
```

Clearly the problem is that the update script (maybe just at that point) is trying to do something to clientname_live. What I don't understand is where it's getting that information from. The config file points at clientname_dev and the site is definitely running from *that* data base and not the live one.

Where could this database name be stored other than in the config file?

Comment: Have you done a search in all the files and the db dump for "clientname_live"? That's what i would do....

Comment: Yes, no sign of it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a **exp_layout_publish** table in the database now?

Just a thought as before that error (line 1583) there are a few tables created and if these are being created then there is definitely something rather strange going on there as why would it be able to find the database and create those tables but then throw a wobbly later on?

Did you clear all caches on the site?

Last but not least where is your dev site hosted? Is this on a local machine or on the same server as the live site? You're definitely trying to update the correct site aren't you? ;-)

Comment: I'm unable to check whether there isa n exp_layout_publish table at the moment... will report back.

Yes, I cleared the cache more than once!

The dev site is on a remote server, it is part of the same setup as the live site but not necessarily on the same physical box. I can check that. Either way, the boxes *should* be absolutely identical (and I've never had a problem like this previously despite creating clones the same way many times though not doing an EE1->2 update).

Comment: Actually looking again at your error it's saying that the exp_weblog_fields doesn't exist. I didn't take that in before but does your database now have exp_channel_fields in it or no table of that sort at all? Seems like it may have updated the tables to channel but is now having some problem knowing that. I personally would try the whole thing again as something may have gone awry somewhere.

Comment: The problem is that it's looking at the *wrong* database all together. I'm guessing some of the updates have happened on the clientname_dev database but for some reason the update script is trying to do this to the clientname_live database (from which I originally cloned this dev site). That's the puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

Look at line 1583 in the upgrade file. It'll tell you exactly what's trying to be done and where the name is coming from. Track backwards from there.

The DB settings are only stored in the config file. However, could be something in a template or addon.